# How to write Schmidt decomposition for pure tripartite state?

Tags: schmidt-decomposition

Supposing a pure tripartite state, i wrote schmidt decomposition as follows

$\sum_{}^{r}p_{ijk}|i\rangle|j\rangle|k\rangle$

Did i write it correctly?

Like pure bipartite states If r>1 then the state is entangled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Schmidt decomposition exists, it would be written as:
$$\sum_{i=1}^rp_i\left|i_A\right\rangle\left|i_C\right\rangle\left|i_B\right\rangle$$
With $\left\{\left|i_A\right\rangle\right\}_i$, $\left\{\left|i_B\right\rangle\right\}_i$ and $\left\{\left|i_C\right\rangle\right\}_i$ being orthonormal basis of the respective Hilbert space.

Writing it like this allows to have a single index, and thus to define the Schmidt number $r$. However, you have to be careful, in that the Schmidt decomposition doesn't always exist for more than two systems. [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9504006.pdf) gives necessary and sufficient conditions for it to exist for higher number of systems.

Assumming it exists however, we can show that if $r>1$, then at least two registers are entangled. This is equivalent to showing that if the three registers are not entangled with one another, then $r=1$.

Let us assume that $\left|\psi_{ABC}\right\rangle$ can be written as $\left|\varphi_A\right\rangle\otimes\left|\varphi_B\right\rangle\otimes\left|\varphi_C\right\rangle$. We can find orthonormal bases for the three respective Hilbert spaces such that these states are members of these basis, which matched our writing above.

Thus, if $r>1$, then at least two registers are entangled.

Comment: Ty. How you know for r>1, there is entanglement? Can u share resource please? I wanna study more about it

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood your question, what are you looking for? @reza

Comment: I want to know how to prove there is entanglement for r>1? Is there any article about it?

Comment: That's what I proved in my answer! To prove $A\implies B$ is equivalent to prove that $\overline{A}\implies\overline{B}$. In that case, proving that $r>1$ implies entanglement is equivalent to prove that if there is no entanglement then $r\leqslant1$!